# Determining outcome variable for propensity score matching in STATA - is my understanding correct

Tags: stata, matching, propensity-scores

I am a little confused in what to use for my outcome variable, when implementing the PSM technique in STATA.

In brief, my study is looking at the abnormal returns  (returns in food firm - returns in market proxy) in the food industry during some yearly event from 2000-2010. The food industry are the public US firms classified under food, and the market proxy are all the public US firms.

I am matching on two firm characteristics, which I have data on.

If I am not mistaken, my outcome variable should be of this nature:
$$ outcome =$$ $$Avg \space Abnormal \space Return = \frac{1}{10} \sum_{t=1}^{10}  (Food \space Firm \space)_{i,t}  - (Public \space US\space Firms \space Ret)_t  $$

Now, $(Public \space US\space Firms \space Ret)$ is my market proxy. It has its' own constituent firms. 
After running the PSM, I should get appropriately matched firms between the $Food \space firms$ and the $Public \space US \space Firms$, of the nature:
$(Food \space firm)_k$ is matched with $(Public \space US \space Firm)_m$.

Then, PSM will work by calculating abnormal returns such that instead of
$$(Food \space Firm \space)_{i,t}  - (Public \space US\space Firms \space Ret)_t$$
It does $$(Food \space Firm \space)_{k,t}  - (Public \space US\space Firms \space Ret)_{m,t}$$

Is my understanding of what to use as the outcome variable correct?

I can attach some sample data if that helps in understanding my dilemma/scenario.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what all the subscripts means? Specifically, what is t?

Comment: Sorry, i and k are just different firms at time t in days.
m is for the returns on the total US Market.

Comment: You will want to aggregate the returns for food firms and non-food firms for the 10 years in whatever way makes sense. That is is your outcome. Then you would use `psmatch2` on this cross-sectional dataset to do PSM. This will tell you the effect of being a food firm.